# Practical applications of modern particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, applied-physics

I'm a wholehearted supporter of scientific discoveries. "IFLS!" Nevertheless, I'm curious what non-scientists gain from *[unlocking the mysteries of the universe](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/magazine/the-sunday-times-magazine/will-cerns-large-hadron-collider-finally-unlock-the-mysteries-of-the-universe-xdmgbk8st)*. I found a lot of articles like these:

- https://symmetrymagazine.org/article/march-2013/how-particle-physics-improves-your-life
- http://nautil.us/issue/14/mutation/10-reasons-why-you-cant-live-without-a-particle-accelerator
- https://www.fnal.gov/pub/science/particle-physics/benefits/

All of those practical uses are based on particles discovered before 1950, with energy levels under 10 MeV. None of them needed LHC, SNS, SLC, or even SPS. (Regarding the side-effect of grid computing, any giga-cost project with ultra-high data rate would have reached the same result.)

Are there technologies - existing, in development, or even a serious published proposal - with products or effects that benefit common consumers, whose design requires knowledge of quarks, neutrinos, Tau, W/Z/Higgs bosons, dark matter, super-particles, or anti-atoms?

Comment: Absolutely not. You should only care about practical applications of these things if you would like scifi to ever become reality. We can live just fine _now_ without them.

Comment: I have reworded the question to eliminate opinion-based answers. I am looking for actual citations - scientific research, business plans, or mainstream news media - about specific technologies with specific requirements. If there is a valid reason not to allow this question, please state it.

Comment: Let's ignore side-effects from the technologies that have to be invented in order to *do* PPE (cryogenics, vaccum, RF, computing, etc.) and just concentrate on the particles. In this case, you've answered your own question - particles that _today_ do a job, were discovered 70 years ago. This gives us a time-constant of the order of a century between discovery and application. So, come back in 2115 and we'll probably have space captains ordering, "Engage the Higgs Drive!".

Comment: Speaking of side developments, let's not forget that HTTP & HTML started at CERN.

Answer (score 1):

Anti-neutrino detectors can be used to monitor nuclear reactors. Right now the most promising application is for non-proliferation (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/888/1/012010/meta ), but theoretically, it can be used also for process control. The benefit for common consumers is the ability to get more electricity from nuclear power stations with less danger of becoming "consumers" of rogue nuclear bombs produced as a result of proliferation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that we just don't know. It's certain the founders of quantum mechanics couldn't have predicted their work would lead to the development of the flash drive. Similarly current cutting edge physics could lead anywhere. It's folly to think we can predict the future impact of fundamental science.